# Bootstrap generic modal with callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, callback, bootstrap-modal

I've replace my JS `Confirm` function with a bootstrap modal, this modal is async so I also had to change my code and add callbacks.

What I'm trying to is:

**Pseudo Code**

```
if `simApp["con1"]` then show first modal with 2 buttons
    if return is clicked -> close modal.
    if continue is clicked -> open second modal
        if return is clicked -> close modal
        if submit is clicked -> submit form (not included in code)
else open second modal
    if return is clicked -> close modal
    if submit is clicked -> submit form (not included in code)
```

This is all very simple when you don't use callbacks, which I'm fairly new to.

So this is what I did, its **NOT** working, I guess it has something to do with the generic use of the modal. - [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LiranBo/53Lyv4ez/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="generalModalTwoButtons" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btn-return" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <button type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="go">GO</button>
```

**JS**

```
simApp = {};
simApp["con1"] = true;  //in this code I hard-coded the conditions to ture
simApp["arr"] = [1];

$("#go").click(function () {
    if (simApp["con1"] && simApp["arr"].length < 5) {
        var msg = '<p>msg1</p>';

        updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal('#a94442', 'header1', msg, 'Return', 'Continue', function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                confirmBeforeSubmit(submitFormApproved);
            }
        });
    } else {
        confirmBeforeSubmit(submitFormApproved)
    }
});

function submitFormApproved(result) {
    if (result === true) {
        console.warn("submitted");
    }
}

function confirmBeforeSubmit(callback) {
    var msg = '<p>msg2</p>';
    if (simApp["con1"]) msg = '<p>msg2-changed</p>';

    updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal('#31708f', 'header2', msg, 'Return', 'Submit', callback);
}

function updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal(color, title, body, btnReturn, btnSubmit, callback) {
    var confirm = $('#generalModalTwoButtons');
    confirm.find('.modal-header').css('color', color);
    confirm.find('.modal-title').text(title);
    confirm.find('.modal-body').html(body);
    confirm.modal('show');

    confirm.find('#btn-return').html(btnReturn).off('click').click(function () {
        confirm.modal('hide');
        callback(false);
    });
    confirm.find('#btn-submit').html(btnSubmit).off('click').click(function () {
        confirm.modal('hide');
        callback(true);
    });

}
```

Any idea what I did wrong?

**P.S** - for learning purposes I would like to avoid using promises on this solution.

Comment: I think you have to start from the official [docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals). It has lot of details and examples.

Comment: @hindmost I already did, it is working perfectly as well, the only part that isn't working is the modal after modal... the issue is in the callbacks somehow..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go, the main problem I found was the fact that you don't block the propagation of the click event which automatically closes the modals.  I added the event handler stopPropagation in the event of the continue/submit button.

```js
simApp = {};
simApp["con1"] = true;
simApp["arr"] = [1];

$("#go").click(function () {
    if (simApp["con1"] && simApp["arr"].length < 5) {
        var msg = '<p>msg1</p>';

        updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal('#a94442', 'header1', msg, 'Return', 'Continue', function (result) {
            if (result === true) {
                confirmBeforeSubmit(submitFormApproved);
            }
        });
    } else {
        confirmBeforeSubmit(submitFormApproved)
    }
});

function submitFormApproved(result) {
    if (result === true) {
        console.warn("submitted");
    }
}

function confirmBeforeSubmit(callback) {
    var msg = '<p>msg2</p>';
    if (simApp["con1"]) msg = '<p>msg2-changed</p>';

    updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal('#31708f', 'header2', msg, 'Return', 'Submit', callback);
}


function updateGeneralTwoButtonsModal(color, title, body, btnReturn, btnSubmit, callback) {
    var confirm = $('#generalModalTwoButtons');
    confirm.find('.modal-header').css('color', color);
    confirm.find('.modal-title').text(title);
    confirm.find('.modal-body').html(body);
    confirm.modal('show')
    

    confirm.find('#btn-return').html(btnReturn).off('click').click(function () {
        confirm.modal('hide');
        
        callback(false);
    });
    confirm.find('#btn-submit').html(btnSubmit).off('click').click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
        if(btnSubmit != "Continue") {
         confirm.modal('hide');
        }
        callback(true);
    });

}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="generalModalTwoButtons" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header bg-primary">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                 <h4 class="modal-title"></h4>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body"></div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" id="btn-return" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
                <button type="button" id="btn-submit" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<button id="go">GO</button>
```

Comment: looks good, do you mind explaining why you added those 2 lines? what exactly is it stopping?

Comment: Most events, especially mouse and keyboard input actions have a propagation effect, so the event passes through the parent elements as well. If you click in a div which is inside another div you are essentially clicking both.  The first line prevents the default behavior of a link or button to occur, and the second one prevents the event from bubbling up through the DOM so that the modal doesn't close.